# How to get the ldap url for an AWS Simple AD deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap

I have an AWS Simple AD deployment. I need the ldap_url. I have seen it represented in various forms such as simply [ldap://example.com](http://eng.localytics.com/implementing-a-centralized-directory-service-for-aws-infrastructure-with-amazon-simple-ad-and-sssd/) and also [ldap://aws-[some-mysterious-id].whatever.com](https://auth0.com/blog/simple-guide-to-setup-aws-directory-service/) and even in some AWS documentation they simply use the LAN IP of one of the instances, which I can't find anywhere in the AWS console since the EC2 console hides your Simple AD servers just like it does not show your RDS instances either.

When using ldapsearch to query against the value represented by "Directory name" in the AWS Console for Directory Services, the result is `ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`, so it does not appear to be that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to the AWS Directory Service console https://console.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/home
2. Select your directory.
3. Under DNS address will be two IP addresses.

Note that these addresses are private IP addresses in your VPC.

If you need public Internet access to your Simple AD server, then put an ELB -> HA Proxy -> Simple AD in front. Add Route53 to provide a DNS name.

Comment: First off, thanks for your reply John.  I actually figured it out just by attempting the connection with that, even though it made no sense (read on) .. I am by no means an expert devops person (yet) so when I saw those `DNS` IP addresses I thought of DNS ... in other words ... I think of Domain Name Server ... not Light Directory Access Protocol server. Can you see the misnomer this creates by labeling things this way??  Since these are actually the addresses of the Samba 4 hosts themselves, I really think they need to not name that field "LDAP server addresses".  Call a spade a spade, eh?

Comment: Your points bring up good issues. I have been working with these types of systems for so long that I take for granted how confusing the terminology can be at times.

Comment: I just tested using the new NLB (Network Load Balancer) directly in front of Simple AD. The configuration was very easy. Now to verify that NLB actually works with LDAP with our client software. Using NLB would be easier than using HA Proxy in front of Simple AD.

Comment: `Using NLB would be easier than using HA Proxy in front of Simple AD` - it depends I would say. HA proxy drones are pretty easy to pop out with CloudFormation and Ansible and offer a lot more flexibility.

Comment: @Michael. Good point but HA Proxy needs an EC2 instance with its own costs and management. However, I like HA Proxy for this use case. Amazon gives us lots of options ...

Comment: Exactly. Actually for my immediate use case I would not spawn more EC2 instances, but instead we're simply going to pop out HA Proxy Docker containers on existing EC2 instances. That way we also don't need to pay for NLB.